# List of entities not remembering previously added entities for a one-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two entities one for a class another for a student and I have a list of registered students in the class entity. The problem I'm having is that after I add one student to the list of RegisteredStudents and then log off and log back in as another student and try to register another student, the RegisteredStudents list is empty! It doesn't remember the previously added student.

FYI - this is EF 6+, ASP.Net MVC

Here is my code.

Parent entity with list of children

```
public class Event
{
   public Event() {
       RegisteredStudents = new List<Student> ();
   }

   public int Name{ get; set; }
   public DateTime Time{ get; set; }
   // other properties

   public List<Student> RegisteredStudents { get; set; }
}
```

Child entity that is being added to the list in the parent

```
public class Student
{
   public Student() {}

   public int Name{ get; set; }
   public DateTime Time{ get; set; }
   // other properties
}
```

Here is how I'm adding a new student entity. I get an event and student

then I add the student. This is done in a service class method and so if I have logged in as a new student it will be the same event but a different student. Either way the list is empty after added the first student and saving the context.

```
var student= dbContext.Profiles.Where(i => i.ApplicationUserGuid == userId).First(); 
var event = dbContext.SpaceEvents.Where(j => j.SpaceEventId == eventId).First();
```

// do some other studff here then add the student

```
event.RegisteredStudents.Add(student);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

when I hover over RegisteredStudents after adding a single student and trying now to add a second, it's empty!

Comment: We need more information. Where/when do you call the `Save`/`SaveChanges` method? Is this EF1, EF4, EF5, EF6 or EF Core? Is this WinForms/WPF, or UWP or ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Core? Where is the rest of your data-loading code and query definitions? What does your EF Context look like?

Comment: I'll update the post

Comment: `dbContext.SaveChanges();` does it saves the student in RegisteredStudents table?

Comment: no it doesn't create a RegisteredStudents table! All it does is add a reference in the Student table called something like 'Event_EventId' and it puts the id in the cell.

Comment: `dbContext.Entry(event).State = EntityState.Modified;` Try to add this line before calling .Add(student) in your code.

Comment: Also, does your Student holds an object from Event or list of Events? I mean if its one-to-many relationship or many-to-many if its a list

Answer (score 0):

As your title suggests its one-to-many relationship so I assume your student class looks like the following

```
public class Student
{
   public Student() {}

   public int Name{ get; set; }
   public DateTime Time{ get; set; }
   // other properties
   public string EventId {get;set;}

   public virtual Event Event {get; set; }
}
```

First make sure your entities are loaded correctly coming directly from db context. Some information on loading entities

> Lazy loading is the process whereby an entity or collection of
>   entities is automatically loaded from the database the first time that
>   a property referring to the entity/entities is accessed. When using
>   POCO entity types, lazy loading is achieved by creating instances of
>   derived proxy types and then overriding virtual properties to add the
>   loading hook. [MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx)

You can try the following things to properly add students to an event

1) Update event in Student's object

```
student.Event = event; //add this line here 
event.RegisteredStudents.Add(student);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

2) Update foreign key in student's table

```
student.EventId = event.Id; //or add this line
event.RegisteredStudents.Add(student);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

3) Check the state of Event and update it accordingly

```
var state = dbContext.Entry(event).State;
if(state == EntityState.Detached)
     dbContext.Events.Attach(event);
dbContext.Entry(event).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

I will suggest you to read more about loading related entities [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx) if you still face any issue

Comment: well I changed the RegisteredStudents property from a list to a virtual ICollection and then added a virtual event to the student entity and now it works, but why is a virtual needed? and whhy is a virtual Icollection needed

Comment: additionaly, why is it that when I look at the student table and look at the reference back to the event table I only see the last event id in that cell? Ex. 70, but don't see the event id I added before that 69

Comment: Any virtual ICollections will be lazy-loaded unless you specifically mark them otherwise. You can attach the registered students collection in your event by marking it virtual (so it loads automatically in lazyloading). If you remove the virtual keyword and don't use `.Include` you will see no Students are attached but marking them virtual will load the students in your collection on first access

Comment: You will only see the last updated value i.e 70 in this case because its one-to-many relationship and you student can only be attached to one Event. So whenever you perform any update on `Student`'s event, it will always update the previous value instead of adding a new row

Comment: this is starting to sound a little confusing! maybe I'm just tired, but the only requirement I have is that I need to let students register and unregister for classes when they want! as long as this implementation gives me that I'm good!

Comment: Give it a try with any one of above solutions and it should work! Remember to mark your properties as virtual here